# How do I load the Bootstrap CSS into a CKEditor template?

Tags: wysiwyg, bootstrap-theme

Just how we add custom theme style, I want to add Bootstrap CSS. Is there a way to do it?

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_ckeditor_css_alter().
 */
function mymodule_ckeditor_css_alter(array &$css, Editor $editor) {
  $css[] = \Drupal::service('extension.list.theme')->getPath('my_theme') . '/css/styles.css';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The body classes in ckeditor start with cke_. So I created a _ckeditor.scss file with most of the classes I used on my site, wrapped in body.cke_editable and then included that file in my style.scss.

Should work with straight up css included via THEME.info.yml or THEME.libraries.yml